# How to sort PHP array of objects by a value inside an object in each element?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is a simplified version of the array. It is easy to sort this by 'id', or 'created_by', but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to sort it by the value of "e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd" inside the 'elements' object. I've spent hours searching through other questions trying to figure this out, but with no luck.

So here's the simplified version of the array via print_r:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},


"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "Aeronca"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "L-3B"
    }
}

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},


"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "BEECHCRAFT"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "N-35"
    }
}

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 13
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},

"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "AEROSPORT"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": ""
    }
}

    )
```

So basically the array, when sorted, should have the first element be where it is now, followed by the third element, followed by the second, so it would look like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 12
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},


"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "Aeronca"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "L-3B"
    }
}

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 13
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},

"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "AEROSPORT"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": ""
    }
}

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [created_by] => 776
        [searchable] => 1
        [elements] =>  {
"b2c4ecaa-f68f-4a5c-a551-339aa8f01421":  {

},


"e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "BEECHCRAFT"
    }
},

"d7c903a8-fa15-4620-9d9b-2238cb48fd5c":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "N-35"
    }
}

    )
```

Keep in mind that the actual array is far more complex, and contains close to 1,000 elements in the array, so hopefully whatever method I use would minimize load on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create your own comparator function and use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for sorting.

For example:

```
function myComparator($a, $b) {
    return  $a->someValue - $b->someValue;
}
```

The return value explained in php.net:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

And somewhere in your code where you want to sort the array:

```
usort($arrayOfObjects, 'myComparator');
```

Comment: I did the following based on your answer, and it works like a charm:
   function myComparator($a, $b) {
    $json_var =  json_decode($a->elements, true);
    $first = $json_var['e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd'][0]['value'];
    $json_var =  json_decode($b->elements, true);
    $second = $json_var['e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd'][0]['value'];
    return strcmp ( $first , $second );
}

usort($arrayOfObjects, 'myComparator');

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to decode the json and create a key array.  Then use the key array and array_multisort() to sort by whatever order you want:

```
foreach($object as $k => $o) {
    //PHP 5.4.0
    //$key[$k] = json_decode($o->elements, true)['e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd'][0]['value'];
    $elements = json_decode($o->elements, true);
    $key[$k]  = $elements['e5e53240-1d5a-4b50-ad7d-cfa00f33badd'][0]['value'];
}
```