# Sorting array from db query by one column of the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to take the results from an array from a database query and sort by one of the columns in the results? If so, how would that be done?

Here is an example of the array that I have:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [item] => 0 [size] => 2056515 [group] => SF2K [description] => 205/65R15 SAFFIRO SF2000 94V 40K [sort4] => 94 [sort5] => V [sort6] => [price] => 69.14 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [item] => 8518 [size] => 2056515 [group] => FTOUR [description] => 205/65R15 FUZION TOUR BW 94H 40K [sort4] => 94 [sort5] => H [sort6] => [price] => 77.63 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [item] => 106633 [size] => 2056515 [group] => SEREN [description] => 205/65R15 BS TURANZA SER+ 94H 80K [sort4] => 94 [sort5] => H [sort6] => [price] => 124.07 ) )

I would like to sort it by [price]. I know that in this example they are all already in numerical order, but they are not always.

Comment: If you really want to do this in PHP, you can use the approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19253751/1615903 - however, `ORDER BY` statement in your SQL query will be much better.

Comment: I have the database ordered by price and I have an ORDER BY in my SQL query, the problem is another function that I cannot remove from the template changing the ORDER BY after my query. This is not a permanent solution, just a temporary fix so I have time for a real solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real solution is to fix your code so you can use `order by` statement in your query.

That said, to do this in php, create a comparator function:

```
function myComparator($a, $b) {
    return $a->price - $b->price;
}
```

Then, on your array, let's call it `$myArray`, call:

```
usort($myArray, 'myComparator');
```

See [php.net documentation on usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for more details.

Comment: I appreciate your help even though I am doing this wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the SQL query itself. Add one of the following to the end of your query:

Ascending order (lowest first):

```
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Descending order (highest first):

```
ORDER BY price DESC
```

Comment: $tire_sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT item, size, `group`, description, sort4, sort5, sort6, price FROM _tires WHERE size = %d AND sort5 != '' ORDER BY price ASC", $size );

That is what I currently have, my problem is that this page template is heavy incorporated into the theme of the website. There is a function that is calling an order by itself after my query. So I need to resort. I know this is a horrible thing to do, but I am just in a crunch to get it working, then I will have time to rewrite it after.

Comment: If those are your limitations, then you must do what you have to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add "ORDER BY price DESC(or ASC, depending on your needs)" to your SQL query

Comment: After my sql query and before my results display there is a function that is part of the WordPress template that I cannot change or remove that is changing the order after my query. So I was hoping there was a way to sort the array by one of the columns from the db that I can add after the template's function that is reordering.

Comment: I see...you can try this one, then:

function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["price"] - $b["price"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp");